# Error when tyring to push my docker image in Heroku: Registry v2 schema1 support will be removed in an upcoming release

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile

I was working in my web app created in a Docker container and I was able to upload my docker images and release them through heroku simply with:

```
sudo heroku container:push web -a dashboard-container
sudo heroku container:release web -a dashboard-container
```

However, when I bought a domain through Godaddy (didn't have any other alternative) and then I added it to Heroku

```
heroku domains:add www.mydashboard.xyz -a dashboard-container
heroku domains:add *.mydashboard.xyz -a dashboard-container
```

and tried to push my web app docker image I encountered the following:

```
[DEPRECATION NOTICE] registry v2 schema1 support will be removed in an upcoming release. Please contact admins of the registry.heroku.com registry NOW to avoid future disruption. More information at https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/deprecated-schema-v1/
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
▸    Error: docker push exited with Error: 1
```

Previous to this error I was able to push and release my docker images in Heroku several times but when I added my domain then I encountered this error. Why by adding adding and configuring this domain I get this error? How can I do the update to the new version 2 schema 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I was able to push the image and release it after I left past a couple of hours. I honestly don't know what happened internally but in other posts I read this has something to do with the registry of the container in heroku (see [heroku/cli/issues/1081](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1081)).